# Launch a file script after the first one is done

Tags: bash, shell

I will be on 3 days vacation, so I would like to do a task in one file, after it's done, launch the other one using bash script, the way I would like to do is:

- List files location in one file, i.e (`toDo.txt`)
- Once the first file is done it goes to the other one.

Example:

`doDo.txt` contents:

```
/home/me/www/some_dir/file1F42.sh
/home/me/www/another_dir/fileD2cD.sh
/home/me/www/third_dir/fileG0IU.sh
/home/me/www/last_dir/fileVFpO.sh
```

`file1F42.sh`:

```
some commands here
```

Once is done, it should jump to line 2, which is: `fileD2cD.sh`

I do NOT want to use `cron`, because I do not know when the files will finish treatment, and at the same time I do NOT want to launch all of them at once.

This is a real example that I just finish to do:

```
ffmpeg -i Original/$domainName"_"$fileName"_"$f-Original.mp4 -strict experimental -vf "drawtext=fontfile='/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSansBold.ttf':text='www.alfirdaous.com':x="$SizeX":y="$SizeY":fontsize="$textSize":fontcolor=$textColor" -vcodec libx264 -preset medium -crf 24 -acodec copy Done/"$domainName"_"$fileName"_$f-Done.mp4

mp4Box=$(MP4Box -add Done/"$domainName"_"$fileName"_$f-Done.mp4 "$domainName"_"$fileName"_$f.mp4)

echo $mp4Box >> ffmpeg_exec.log;

# Delete Done files
rm Done/"$domainName"_"$fileName"_$f-Done.mp4

# Get master thumbnail
ffmpeg -itsoffset -150 -i "$domainName"_"$fileName"_$f.mp4 -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s 640x480 "$silsilaName"_$f.png

n=0
for offset in 140 160 180 200 220 240 260 280 300 320
do
printf -v outfile "$silsilaName"_"$f"_"%03d.png" "$((++n))"

ffmpeg -itsoffset -$offset -i $domainName"_"$fileName"_"$f.mp4 -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s 640x480 "$outfile"
```

done

```
ffmpeg -i "$domainName"_"$fileName"_$f.mp4 -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 128 -f mp3 $f.mp3
done
```

Last command line is:
    ffmpeg -i "$domainName"*"$fileName"*$f.mp4 -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 128 -f mp3 $f.mp3

How do I know that it is DONE, finish, so I can go to my file list "doDo.txt" and start running the next file?

Comment: Your file of commands is already a valid script.

Comment: Once todo.txt is generated, just run: sh todo.txt

Comment: I edited my question above with a real example

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /bin/sh

while read file; do
    echo "Executing $file"
    sh "$file"
done < /dev/stdin
```

Where usage is `<script.sh> < file_list`

Comment: Thanks s8129, but which file will execute? Executing 
sh: : No such file or directory

Comment: What does the first line of the while statement print to stdout? To be honest though, I have completely overthought this, and, as  tripleee's comment on your original post states, the list of files you have should be useable (assuming all files are executable). If not, run `chmod 775 *.sh` in the directory that contains all these files

Comment: I edited my question above with a real example